# Handling NSSegmentedControl selected segment change in Cocoa

Tags: cocoa, nstoolbar, nssegmentedcontrol, responder-chain

Forgive the super noob question, but I've been googling this for the past hour and am getting frustrated that I can't seem to find an answer to such a very basic question:

How do I handle control changes in Cocoa?

I'm coming from iOS, and it's clear that Cocoa does not use outlets or delegates to handle events in the same way that UIKit does and I feel like I'm just missing some very important piece of information here. I've figured out that it uses the first responder chain, but beyond that I can't figure out how to actually do it, or how to even find where these events are defined or documented.

So I have a `NSSegmentedControl` inside a `NSToolBar` and I just want to know when a user changes the selected segment. I've pored through the class documentation but cannot see a *single* mention of any kind of events or actions to handle. I did notice if I drag the control's `action` outlet onto my first responder proxy, I get a quadrillion different actions listed, none of which seem relevant in any way.

How on earth do I do this in Cocoa?

Comment: A connected action to an `IBAction` works the same way like in iOS. A very smart way which is not available in iOS is Cocoa Bindings.

Comment: Where might I find these actions? I looked at the bindings, but it looks like super overkill. I just want a signal or method call or something.

Comment: Create an `IBAction` in the target class and connect the action in Interface Builder (it's the same as in iOS). Bindings are not overkill, far from it. In most cases it's less code.

Comment: Thanks @vadian, I dragged the `action` outlet into my class and it created a generic action outlet which does indeed get called when the segment changes. I guess I was looking for something a little more specific.

Comment: NSSegmentedControl has a `.selectedSegment: Int` property.

Comment: Maybe try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24927874/how-to-draw-segmented-control-with-blue-tint-like-xcode/25134440#25134440

Answer (score 5):

This is a code from one of my projects

```
var currntSeg : Int = 1
@IBOutlet weak var acSwitch: NSSegmentedControl!
@IBAction func SwitchButton(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    switch acSwitch.selectedSegment {
    case 0:
        currntSeg == 0 ?
            self.navVC?.pushViewController(Sleeper!, animated: true) :
            self.navVC?.popViewController(Sleeper!, animated: true)
    case 1:
        currntSeg < 1 ?
            self.navVC?.pushViewController(Work!, animated: true) :
            self.navVC?.popViewController(Work!, animated: true)
    case 2:
        currntSeg < 2 ?
            self.navVC?.pushViewController(Student!, animated: true) :
            self.navVC?.popViewController(Student!, animated: true)
    default:
        self.navVC?.pushViewController(Rose!, animated: true)
    }
    currntSeg = acSwitch.selectedSegment
    print("Selected Seg: \(acSwitch.selectedSegment)")
}
```

Comment: `acSwitch.selectedSegment` holds the value of the selected segment
`SwitchButton(_ sender: AnyObject)` is an IBAction connected to the segment too.